# How to redirect a subdomain to another subdomain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect a subdomain to another subdomain that is not on the same domain.

Example:

subdomain.mydomain.com --> subdomain.myotherdomain.com

I've tried the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.myotherdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond doesn't seem to work...

Could you guys help me?

Thank you,
Damien

Comment: Nothing wrong in these conditions. .htaccess might not be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way in your subdomain root htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.myotherdomain.com [R=301,L]
```